# Get the latest objects and order by a different field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I would like to run a query that :

**Get from the table "Media" the latest objects (created_at) and order them based on "likes".**
(please look at the example to understand what I mean by "latest")

example :

```
media_id  -   created_at   -   likes 
media_1   -   11/03/2017   -   12
media_2   -   10/03/2017   -   13
media_1   -   06/03/2017   -   8
media_3   -   02/03/2017   -   6
```

Here, we got media_1 2 times, i would like to keep only the latest one (created_at). Then, i would like to order by '-likes'.

would return :

```
media_id  -   created_at   -   likes 
media_2   -   10/03/2017   -   13
media_1   -   11/03/2017   -   12
media_3   -   02/03/2017   -   6
```

I tried to run this, but it throws an error message :
    MyQuery.order_by('media_id', '-created_at').distinct('media_id').order_by('-likes')

EDIT :

I don't know how it can help, but here is my model :

```
instagram_user = models.ForeignKey(SocialAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
media_id = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
type = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
link = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
likes = models.IntegerField()
comments = models.IntegerField()
location = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
images = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
videos = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
link = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
tags = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
filter = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
caption = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
user_has_liked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
attribution = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
users_in_photo = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
created_time = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.media_id

class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Instagram Media"
```

Comment: Please share your `models.py` file, please?

Comment: please find the model in the edit

Comment: You're not being very clear. How are you getting the "latest" if you're ordering by likes? What determines the latest?

Comment: Latest means latest date (created_at) - I will try to explain more by editing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
qv = Query.objects.order_by('-created_at','-likes')[:0]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer but i am not sure you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Get from the table "Media" the latest objects and order it based on "likes".

You are not declaring **how latest** you want the objects to be (!)

Assuming a 5 day then:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now_dt = datetime.now()
before_5_days = now_dt - timedelta(days=5)

# Get from the table "Media" the latest (5 days) objects and order them based on "likes".
Media.objects.filter(created_at__lte=now_dt, created_at__gte=before_5_days).order_by('likes')
```